Change the color of one or more specific items on the Pages list (Admin)
This screenshot shows a page called OO01 - TRABALHOS HOVOS I've created to demonstrate this.
This page is listed in the All Pages section of Wordpress.

All pages there are listed with the same blue color.
I wonder if there is a way, a plugin, or something, to change the color of some specific entries in that listing to other colors, while keeping the remaining blue.
Thanks

Would be something like this, where 3 in #post-3 is the ID of the page (untested):
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit.php', static function() {
    ?>

    <style>.table-view-list.pages #post-3 a.row-title { color: red; }</style>

    <?php
} );


worked. Added to /includes/admin-filters.php. THANKS!
